# Calculate numbers in MS Word table

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there any way to have MS Word do simple calculations on numbers in a table without going through the rigamarole of copying the table to Excel, doing calcs, and then copying back again? All I need to do is things like "SUM {this column}" and "PRODUCT {this row}". I wouldn't mind doing roundtripping through Excel so much, except that the formatting always gets really messed up and it's too much work to fix that repetitively.

Converting the docs to Excel is not an option as these are from outside our office. I'm using Word 2010.

[image]

Comment: See my answer to similar question at http://superuser.com/questions/1133435/microsoft-word-productleft-for-all-numeric-cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 2007 professional:

Solution 1:

Insert->Table,

when table is created select cell where you need to add formula

then go to Layout->data->formula

dialog box should appear where you might write your formula or choose one from Paste function combobox.

row/column ranges description is similar to excel (column as letters, rows as numbers)

For example sum of first four cells in first column:

`=SUM(a1:a4)`

With this solution you need to update formula manually (to update whole table: select table and press F9)

Solution 2:

Insert->Table->Excel Spreadsheet

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I don't follow what is said in #1. When I select the table and then use "Insert>Table" menu I get options to insert, draw, convert text to table, excel spreadsheet, and quick tables but nothing about layouts or formulas

Comment: @matt wilkie edited, now it should be more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Edited...

Take a look at: [microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/use-a-formula-in-a-word-table-HA102329800.aspx) and  [some other site](http://www.computerfreetips.com/Office_Tips/calculate_office.html)

You're right, in Word 2010 you should do that using the menus. See the "layout" tab, after you click inside your table, in any cell? In the "data" section, there's one button labeled "formula". Click it and insert your formula

In the middle of [this page](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/word-2010-insert-tables-formulas/) you'll find how to do it.

Comment: When I type this in a cell it just shows me the formula text, not the results,e.g. `=100*20` is displayed instead of `2000`.